# Why is my secure iframe being reported as insecure?

Tags: java, iframe, ssl, https, glassfish-3

We have a `Glassfish 3` instance running behind a valid SSL (Windows Server).

In our EAR file, we have a Vaadin application that is mixed with a couple JSP's (mostly for login).

Now, when we log in (which is just a simple HTTP POST on a JSP page), Google Chrome is reporting we are attempting to load insecure content.

So, for example, our URL would be:

```
https://test.example.com/app
```

Because of the way Vaadin works and the way the application was setup, it will automatically redirect to:

```
https://test.example.com/app/ui
```

The `ui` is from the `ui.jsp`.  Now, every link in the entire application is relative.  So the redirect uses:  `/ui.jsp`.

However, the Chrome console reports:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://test.example.com/app/ui` was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://test.example.com/app/ui.jsp': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

The entire application is in the same `WAR` file that is in the same `EAR` file that is deployed to the same application in Glassfish.

Why does it think the content is insecure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a debugging proxy such as Fiddler, what you will see is that although the main URL is served over https; but content such as images, js, or css files are served over http.

This would be because your page specifies the http protocol when building the references to those resources in the main page.